# How to merge an SQL script to an existing SQLite3 database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have following requirements:
I am using a SQLite database which is non-empty. Now I want to add new SQL script to it i.e., to existing database. I tried a lot but could not get the proper result (I tried various software in both the platforms Ubuntu 16.04 and windows 7). Note that I have tried only free version available so please suggest any free version software or tools. Thanking you in advance!
Tried sites:
1. [RebaseData](https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-mysql-to-sqlite-online)
2. [sqlite converter tools](https://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to convert my SQL script to SQLite script from [this site](https://ww9.github.io/mysql2sqlite/). Then as syntax was a little bit different so I have used [DB browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/) and then export it to SQL file. This file helped me understood the syntax in which I should write new converted SQLite file to. Then I copy paste my new SQLite file code into exported real SQL file and then imported it using same DB browser.That's it! First it had looked like rocket science but then it was easier.
[image]

The export/import options may be not visible in the image above so steps are:
File >> import >> Database from SQL file...
or
File >> export >> Database to SQL file...
I hope it may help to save your time. If any point is not clear please ask as I am new to this community.